# Javascript - Evaluate "x(y)"?

Tags: javascript, html, math, eval

So for example, I would like to evaluate 2(3) [which equates to 6].

```
var string = "2(3)";
var ans = eval(string);
```

I typed in the above code in Chrome Console and they gave me the following error message: **TypeError: number is not a function**.

So how do I get **"2(3)"** to return 6? Thx.

Comment: Why would `2(3)` evaluate to 6? This is JavaScript, not math, the semantics are different. You'd have to create your own little parser.

Comment: As an aside, please don't ever use `eval()` ;)

Comment: 2 is a constant. Shouldn't 2(3) be 2 if it was valid?

Comment: Eval is homophonous to evil: don't use it. Ever.

Comment: Write a function like multiply(string) and use it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to insert a `*` between any digit followed by an open bracket to convert your string from `2(3)` to `2*(3)` before passing it through `eval()`:

```
var string = "2(3)",

    // Convert string to array (["2", "(", "3", ")"])
    array = string.split(''),

    ans;

// Insert * between digit and open bracket  (["2", "*", "(", "3", ")"])
array.splice(string.search(/\d\(/) + 1, 0, "*");

// Convert array back to string ("2*(3)")
string = array.join("");

// Run eval (6)
ans = eval(string);

console.log(ans);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4PD/).

Comment: +1 This is great. Even "2(5) + (2+1)" will correctly return 13.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't do that. What you you can do, however, is create a function that returns a function. The second function is called a closure. It's handy because when it's returned it maintains a copy of the local environment it was in when it was created. So you pass in a multiplier parameter to the first function which returns a function. This function, the closure, evaluates the parameter you pass into it when it's called by that multiplier.

[Far better people have explained what a closure is than me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

```
function times(multiplier) {
  return function (num) {
    return num * multiplier;
  }
}

var bySix = times(2);
var result = bySix(3); // 6
```

Comment: The question is "So how do I get "2(3)" to return 6?". With this answer, `2(3)` still returns a Type Error.